# How big of an impact does the Earth's magnetic field have on us?

Tags: magnetic-fields, atmospheric-science, biophysics, geomagnetism

How big of an impact does the earth magnetic field have on us?

Comment: Is there a reason for these down votes? This is a reasonable question.

Comment: @mmesser314 - it is also a very unfocused question with many possible answers depending on what phenomena and physics one wants to consider. For example, I could discuss the impact of the local magnetic field on ion beam propagation through an accelerator. But that might not be what they had in mind at all. Personally, I rate the impact of the Earth's magnetic field as a 7. Units are left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: The downvotes are understandable, but I vote to keep it open, especially if OP edits to specify what kinds of impacts they're talking about.

Comment: Why do we not take into consideration that the magnetic field  is gravity it self ? And the electric particals in our body works with the earth magnetic field ?

Comment: I am sorry, Moe. This is no longer a reasonable question. Gravity and magnetism are very different.

Comment: The reason is that there are equations that clearly show that it's not the same thing. You'd have to really dive into the math to understand this. A unification of forces may be possible, but if that were to happen under a complex mathematical theory, both forces could be explained in terms of the same thing, but that doesn't mean they are the same. Electromagnetism has been unified, but electric and magnetic fields are still different fields. Only that we can explain magnetic fields relating them to their associated electric fields.

Answer (score 2):

It would be impossible to live without it. It deflects charged particles from the Sun, preventing them from directly entering the atmosphere.

Comment: Without it, the solar wind would strip the atmosphere from the Earth over time. Also it is helpful for navigation.

Comment: The magnetic field is not gravity. Gravity is created by the mass of the Earth and acts on all objects with mass. The Earth's core is roughly speaking a magnetic dipole, a permanent magnet with a north pole and a south pole. The magnetic field is generated by the dipole moment of the matter, and by electric currents in the core. In contrast with gravity, it only acts on moving charged objects, not on all objects with mass, and the strength of both fields also greatly differ between each other.

Comment: The magnetic field is oriented, but we fall down to earth and not fall towards the north pole. It may be the same force in an other perspective, like electric and magnetism, but that's the every physicists dream, to unify all the forces.